# If I clicked a button in SSMS, how to track what Windows messages were sent to it?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, autohotkey, windows-messages

I want to do some automation with SQL Server management studio and need to track what Windows messages were sent to it when I click the "Execute" button. Basically what I want to do is:

1. When the user press the "Execute" button or press <kbd>F5</kbd>, intercept it.
2. Check the text in the editor, it the first line is `--sqlcmd`, then change the query mode to "SQLCMD mode". Otherwise ensure the query mode is not "SQLCMD mode".
3. Execute as normal.

I want to use `AutoHotKey`'s `PostMessage` function to do it. However I don't know how to track what messages to post. Anyone can give some suggestions?

[image: look at this]

Comment: Use Spy++ and it might work. But the VS2010 Shell is built on WPF in most places and it doesn't use windows messages except out of necessity.

Comment: I think sending messages to SSMS at the windows level would be alot harder than automating the process with powershell / SQL api.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create you own add-in. You have more control when you work from "inside".
There are some samples and projects available, here is one that I have created:

http://www.ssmsboost.com/create-own-ssms-2012-add-in-sample-code-with-download

Comment: Agreed. I've worked on a project at Red Gate to open up their SSMS extensibility code. 

There's a developer guide here: http://www.red-gate.com/ssmsecosystem/developerresources